# How to add a table in word to a new page

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm trying to create an ongoing letter utilizing records in access and putting them into one giant word document.  In order to do this I need to add the start of a new letter on a new page and the content is stored in tables.  I understand with the code below that it's adding the new table at the end of the content but whatever I try doesn't seem to work, I was hoping someone could enlighten the code a little bit to start off on the next page?

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub CopyTableToEnd(wd As Word.Document, oWordTbl As Object, w As Word.Application)

    Dim rngTableTarget As Word.Range

    Set rngTableTarget = wd.Content

    rngTableTarget.Start = wd.Content.End

    rngTableTarget.FormattedText = oWordTbl.Range.FormattedText

End Sub
```

Comment: In order to provide an optimal solution, it's necessary to know a bit more about how the letters are / should be constructed - there's more than one way to generate a new page. What is at the top of each new page? Can that be formatted with a specific style? If yes, the page break can be included as part of that style? ALSO: Do these letters have Headers and Footers? If yes, should they differ from letter to letter?

Comment: @You can use the [edit] link below the question to include this useful / necessary information in the question, itself. Then you can "ping" me like this: `@cindymeister` *in a comment* so that I'm notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
Sub CopyTableToEnd(wd As Word.Document, oWordTbl As Object, w As Word.Application)

   Dim rngTableTarget As Word.Range

   Set rngTableTarget = wd.Content

   rngTableTarget.Start = wd.Content.End

   rngTableTarget.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

   rngTableTarget.FormattedText = oWordTbl.Range.FormattedText

End Sub
```